# How do I get the template file for a single.php pods page?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am currently using a template file called `single-product.php` and want to check for page template in `header.php`. I've tried using `get_page_template_slug($post->ID)` but it returns empty. I've also tried `is_page_template('single-product.php');` but that returns nothing, as well.

Here's my header. You'll notice that I'm trying to get the template file through `s_page_template('single-product.php')` ny setting it as the value of `$isProductPodTemplate` at the top and use it in the if statement at the bottom:

```
<?php
$page = get_the_title($post->ID);
$frontpageId = get_option('page_on_front');
$isStandardTemplate = is_page_template('standard.php');
$isContactTemplate = is_page_template('contact.php');
$isProductPodTemplate = is_page_template('single-product.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="mainHTML" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Architectural Iron Works</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Architectural Iron Works">
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- <link rel=icon type="img/ico" href=/favicon.ico> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/main.bundle.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("mainHTML").style.display = "none";
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <?php
    if ($post->ID == $frontpageId)
    {
      get_template_part('/includes/_home-header');
      echo "<div class='main-content'>";
    }
    else if (is_404() ||
      $isContactTemplate ||
      $isStandardTemplate)
    {
      get_template_part('/includes/_no-banner-header');
      echo "<div class='main-content no-banner'>";
    }
    else if ($isProductPodTemplate)
    {
      // do something
    }
    else
    {
      get_template_part('/includes/_default-header');
      echo "<div class='main-content'>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I've just tested <? echo get_page_template_slug(); ?> without passing the post ID as param, in my header and I get back my template file name (my-template.php - for example). Can you post your header.php file so we can see how and where you cal this method ?

Comment: @GrantW Do you want to show template name in your header.php file?